# Webpack for loop "i" undefined error

Tags: webpack

i am having a weird problem on using webpack. I'm not using the minify mode on webpack. It seems the for loop isn't working, i keep getting "i" is not defined.

[image]

If i define "var i;" then it works.

But when im using the original files, not the bundle.js, then it perfectly works without the var i.

Any idea on why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 1):

By default JavaScript doesn't enforce variable declaration so sloppy code like this will work:

```
i = 5 + 1
console.log(i)
```

However, webpack, as part of its minification changes var names from long names to minified ones. So:

```
var reallylongvarname
```

might be changed to:

```
var c
```

to help minification. However, in your example since there is no declaration, the minifying process blows up.